# Make parameterized function to return a function to eval

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to parameterize a series of functions for the `ggplot2` plot creation to reduce redundancy.  Below I have what it looks like (and works) without a parameterized function, and my attempt to do so.

I am trying to capture and pass on a parameter value to `geom_vline()` and `geom_text()` in the function `markvline()`, but I want to call `markvline()` inline with the `qplot()` function and return the `geom_vline() + geom_text()` as parameterized, so that they can get evaluated and do the same as what is being done in the first part.

I assume I need to understand quote/eval/substitute a bit better, but I don't at this point.  Any help is appreciated as to how I would construct `markvline()` be the equivalent of the `geom_vline() + geom_text()` calls, with parameters filled out.

```
library(ggplot2)

  ## This works
  ## Making labeled vertical lines at 5 and 6
qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data=iris) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=5, color="red", size=1) +
  geom_text(x=5, y=4, label="5", hjust=0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=6, color="red", size=1) +
  geom_text(x=6, y=4, label="6", hjust=0)


  ## I would like to parameterize these two statements
markvline <- function(e) {
  geom_vline(xintercept=e, color="red", size=1) +
  geom_text(x=e, y=4, label=as.character(e), hjust=0)}

  ## ... but this does not work
qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data=iris) +
  markvline(5) +
  markvline(6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I was able to do is:

```
markvline <- function(e) {
  list(geom_vline(xintercept=e, color="red", size=1),
       geom_text(x=e, y=4, label=as.character(e), hjust=0))}

qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data=iris) +
  markvline(5) + markvline(6)
```

Comment: the list is the good option, but you don't need to add elements independently, just `qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data=iris) + markvline(5) +markvline(6)`

Comment: Thanks!  One of the things this tells me (and some of the error code returns from my example) is that I can return the individual functions as evaluated (into a list, for you), but I can't *combine* them with `+` inside my function.  This hints that somehow `geom_vline()` and `geom_text()` won't combine with each other with `+` on their own, but need to be folded into whatever object `qplot()` returns.  This is a good lead!

Comment: thanks. It was easier than I thought. I'll edit my answer

Comment: This solution works, and so is accepted, thanks.  Now to figure out why this works.  I welcome any comments to that end as well.

Comment: @mpettis I didn't completely grasp why, too. It must be associated with the `ggplot2`-related `method`, and, above all, with how such method deals with lists.

Comment: My best guess as to how this works, so far, is that the `qplot` object is of class(es) `gg` and `ggplot`.  The classes of the `geom_*` objects are of `LayerInstance`, `Layer`, and `ggproto`.  The overloaded `+` operator associates left to right, and is probably defined for adding a `gg` object and `LayerInstance` object to yield a `gg` object.  But it is *not* defined for adding two `LayerInstance` objects.  However, `+` is defined for adding a list of `LayerInstance` objects to a `gg` object.